# How can I find overlapping bricks in LeoCAD?

Tags: software

I've just started using [LeoCAD](https://www.leocad.org/) to generate instructions for a model I want to share.  I've been able to get it working despite the sparse tutorials.  But in looking at my results so far I see that I've got an extra part in one step.  I'm pretty sure this is a left over from duping the same part over and over again.  One benefit of this is that the part must be overlapping with another part.  How can I find and remove this extraneous part?

Comment: The author of LeoCAD also helped me work around a bug I was experiencing to get this far.  https://github.com/leozide/leocad/issues/255  Kudos for excellent free software support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this in LeoCAD directly, but assuming that your overlapping brick is an exact duplicate (same element, same position, same rotation, etc) it will show up as a duplicate line in the LDraw file. Something as simple as this should show you what it is:

```
uniq -d model.ldr
```

You could also use any other tool for finding duplicate lines.

If you find a duplicate, it will look something like this:

```
1 4 -70 -48 -40 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 3005.DAT
```

The 3rd, 4th, and 5th items are the x,y, and z coordinates, which you can use to track down duplicate elements and remove them inside LeoCAD. Alternatively, you can remove all but one of the duplicate lines from the file directly.